# How to read the access token send by the server in Qt creator?

Tags: qt

I ran the inbuilt example of reddit client in Qt creator. The reddit server is sending the access token which is used to get access to some data form reddit sever. I want to read that access token form my code. If anyone knows that inbuilt example, please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: I think we are going to need a lot more detail to make sense of this.  Do you have any code?

Comment: The code is entirely from the inbuilt example. There are multiple files of code. How do I send

Comment: Well, you could try studying the example, find the bit of code that you can't work out how to fix and post that.